# What are these spots on this basil's leaves?

Tags: basil

The affected leaves are widespread in various places on the plants. Might have been related to a recent round of fertilizer, and I have been careful with the watering.
I suspect some fungal disease.

[image: picture of leaves]
[image: picture of plant]
[image: picture of leaf]
[image: picture of leaf]

Comment: Try a LED light at night. Look under the leaves. Insects are glaringly visible then. If none, it's probably some incurable disease.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like sunscald. Evidently these basil plants have been harvested for leaves already, perhaps multiple times, judging by the sprouting from leaf axils and the cut stem ends. The result of this is to expose lower leaves which lived many weeks in the shade of those higher up and are suddenly exposed to direct light. Basil leaf tissues are quite soft and do not really harden up over time. Basil can tolerate quite a bit of direct sun when growing normally, but once the top is harvested needs to be protected from hard direct light.